# How to await an asynchronous bloc event from a WillPopScope function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mvvm, flutter-bloc

Im building a Flutter app which contains multiple surveys based on different topics. There is a *topic_screen* where the topics will be listed and on clicking a topic, the respective *survey_screen* is displayed. I have made use of **flutter_bloc** package for the state management and used **MVVM architecture**.

In the *survey_screen* i have used **WillPopScope()** widget to trigger an autosave event.
This autosave event triggers a block function contains calls to **sqflite** db saving function which is asynchronous.

*survey_screen :*

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
          BlocProvider.of<SurveyBloc>(context).add(SurveyAutoSaveEvent());

          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
           print("After Autosave");
           Navigator.pop(context, BlocProvider.of<SurveyBloc>(context).viewModel);
          });

          return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: //remaining code
```

I have added a **Future.delayed** function here to make sure the bloc function ends before running the function inside **Future.delayed**.

Instead of using **Future.delayed**, is there any other way to know when the particular event's bloc function gets over and then start the **print** and **Navigator.pop**

Answer (score 2):

You just send 'SurveyAutoSaveEvent' at onWillPop of WillPopScope and
call 'Navigator.pop()' when received auto saving completed event using 'BlocListener'.
(If you are using BlocBuilder, use BlocConsumer instead of BlockBuilder and BlocListener.)

```
BlocListener<BlocA, BlocAState> (
      bloc: blocA,
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is SurveyAutoSaveCompleted) {
          print("After Autosave");
            Navigator.pop(context, BlocProvider.of<SurveyBloc>(context).viewModel);
            });
        }
      },
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
            BlocProvider.of<SurveyBloc>(context).add(SurveyAutoSaveEvent());

            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
            

            return false;
        },
        child: //remaining code
    };
```